# jquery drag and drop: Droppable doesnt work on elements with float:left or inline-block

Tags: jquery, droppable

Anyone else have this problem before?

I cannot seem to drop into TARGET that has display: inline-block or float:left.

Here's link to sample code:
http://jsbin.com/arusu3/141

Some info I found:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/connecttosortable-fails-when-sortable-list-is-floated

I noticed if might work INLINE if I dump it EXACTLY in the middle. but it would be nice for it to accept drop if any part of my drag touches.

Comment: Did you try the solution in the thread you linked to?

Comment: Yes, tried it but it didnt help my case. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to drop onto the div-inline. (Using latest Chrome)

Perhaps it's a tolerance issue?

```
    target.droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert('row dropped ' + $(this).text());
        },
        accept: source.selector,
        tolerance: 'touch'
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/arusu3/144 : edited the tolerance to 'touch'

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance

Comment: using `tolerance: "pointer"` also works and allows you to select the dropping location according to the pointer's position

Answer (score 2):

Clear your float.

```
#your_sortable:after { clear:both; content:'.'; display:block; height:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; visibility:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; }
```